# From SQL Server date to VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

I read a date from a SQL Server database through Entity Framework. I return the result to the web page and it's displayed like this :

```
Date(-658436400000)
```

I presume it's something about date format but all my attempt to resolve it lead to an exception.

Here the Entity Framework code in VB:

```vb
Public Function getEvenements(noFacture As String, bd As eFacturationEntities) As Array

    Dim evenements As Array = (
        From e In bd.ItemFactures Where e.NoFacture_cs = noFacture
        Select e Select New With {
            .noEvenement = e.NoEvenement_cn,
            .depart = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.LieuPRCH,
            .arrivee = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.LieuDest,
            .nomBeneficiaire = e.Beneficiaire,
            .NAM = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.NAM,
            .dateDeNaissance = FormatDateTime(e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.DateNaissance_dt),
            .dateDeTransport = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.PRCH_dt,
            .noAs811 = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.NoAS811}).ToArray()

    Return evenements
End Function
```

Comment: The value being displayed looks like the (old) Microsoft JSON date format, so I don't think your issue is necessarily related to your EF code, but... which date property are you talking about, and what is the data type, and how is it being returned to the web page?

Comment: The data is coming from Sql server, the type is date, VB send the JSON data inside an array:                                                                                                             {NO: "123344"
departure: "Somewhere"
birthdate: "/Date(-1569009600000)/"
transportDate: "/Date(1435550400000)/"
arrival: "Somewhere"
noA: "12345"
noEvnt: "12345"
name: "Someone"
}

Answer (score 0):

Solution : call .toString on the date before sending it to the client.

```
.dateDeTransport = e.DetailFactures.FirstOrDefault.PRCH_dt.ToString,
```

But this solution may cause an Exceptionon on some case :

> "LINQ to Entities ne reconnaît pas la méthode 'System.String
>   ToString()', et cette dernière ne peut pas être traduite en expression
>   de   magasin."}   System.Exception

(the french tradcution of VS is unclear ...)